# How to delay the elements the we send to a Channel?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Let's say we have a `Channel` like this

```
private val channel = Channel<String>(1)
```

And we are listening to the `Channel` elements like this

```
channel.receiveAsFlow().collect { myStr ->
    println(myStr)
}
```

If I run something like this

```
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob())
...
fun sendMessage(myMessage: String) {
   scope.launch {
      channel.send(myMessage)
   }
}
...
sendMessage("a")
sendMessage("b")
sendMessage("c")
sendMessage("d")
```

The output is going to be

```
a
b
c
d
```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is that if I send `"b"` it delays the processing of the elements in the channel for 1 second.

For example, if I do

```
...
sendMessage("a")
sendMessage("b")
sendMessage("c")
sendMessage("b")
sendMessage("d")
sendMessage("e")
```

The output that I would expect would be like

```
a // prints immediately
b // prints right after a
c // prints after 1 second
b // prints right after c
d // prints after 1 second
e // prints right after d
```

My question is, how would I achieve this behavior? I've been trying to add `delay()` here and there, but I didn't have any luck.

Comment: Your example may also print `a, c, d, b` or some other sequence. The order is not guaranteed

Comment: The order might be guaranteed if messages are sent from the main thread, especially if the scope uses an immediate dispatcher. Not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea, but it feels a little hacky to me. `trySend` would not work with this. I'm not sure how to make `trySend` make sense with your criteria, because it's supposed to return immediately with a result about whether the value posted.

Here, `send()` suspends until the possible delay is over. If you don't want to wait for it, you'd have to launch a coroutine each time you send something.

Since the Channel "constructor" is not a true constructor, you can't subclass it. My workaround is to create a class that uses it as a delegate.

```
val backingChannel = Channel<String>(1)
val channel = object: Channel<String> by backingChannel {
    var delayNext = false
    val mutex = Mutex()
    override suspend fun send(element: String) = mutex.withLock {
        if (delayNext) {
            delay(1000)
        }
        delayNext = element == "b"
        backingChannel.send(element)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, I haven't properly tested this with a setup that actually guarantees that messages are sent in the order that they're submitted.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try something like this during the weekend and let you know! I've just started with Coroutines a few months ago, so I'm not very saavy yet. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Thanks! It was what I was looking for!